# Специальные директории в с++

Tags: c++

Подскажите как использовать отдельно нужные мне директории для создания папки?

```
CreateDirectory ("C:\\Users\\morons", NULL); // c++
```

Здесь используется: `C:\\Users\\morons`

Как можно взять пути для рабочего стола, папки temp ?

P.S: Например на языке c# Я использовал такой метод:

`string str = string.Concat(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp"), '\\');`

[c#] - папка temp.

`string DesktopDir = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);`

[c#] - рабочий стол

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще раз повторюсь, глядя на ваши вопросы, все, что вы обычно ищите, есть на MSDN.

рабочий стол:

```
TCHAR myPath[ MAX_PATH ];
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, myPath, CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, FALSE);
```

папка temp:

```
TCHAR myPath[ MAX_PATH ];
GetTempPath (MAX_PATH, myPath);
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать)

Comment: Просто буфер передаете и где нужно приведение типов делаете https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx